# If I use the function includeHTML in shiny, javascript based graphing packages dont work

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

Once I add an HTML document in my shiny app my graphs stop populating. I am using bs4dash but shinydashboard also has the exact same issue.

Below is my code as well as a screenshot of what is happening.

Code before i add HTML document

**Ui**

```
library(shiny)
library(bs4Dash)
library(highcharter)
library(plotly)
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
  
      box(width = 12,
          plotlyOutput("plot1")          
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(
    box(
      #width = 12, 
      #includeHTML("first.html")
    )
  )
)
)
```

**Server**

```
server <- function(input, output) {
 
  a = rnorm(100)
  output$plot1 = renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(x = ~a, type = "histogram")
  })
}
```

[image]

Now when i remove the hastags to display my HMTL document. My graph all of a sudden disappears.

**Ui**

```
library(shiny)
library(bs4Dash)
library(highcharter)
library(plotly)
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
  
      box(width = 12,
          plotlyOutput("plot1")          
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(
    box(
      width = 12, 
      includeHTML("first.html")
    )
  )
)
)
```

**Server**

```
server <- function(input, output) {
 
  a = rnorm(100)
  output$plot1 = renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(x = ~a, type = "histogram")
  })
}
```

[image]

I would like to have the graph still show. What is going wrong in the code. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your problem. I just observed that your `fluidRow` is the fourth parameter of `dashboardPage` which, however, expects a `dashboardControlbar`. Both, putting the `fluidRow` into `dashboardBody` or wrapping it in a call to `dashboardControlbar` works for me.

So either it is your  `first.html` or indeed "just" the missing `dashboardControlbar`.

### `first.html`

```html
<span>I am an external HTML</span>
```

### `app.R`

```r
library(shiny)
library(bs4Dash)
library(highcharter)
library(plotly)
ui <- dashboardPage(
   dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
   dashboardSidebar(),
   dashboardBody(
      box(width = 12,
          plotlyOutput("plot1")          
      ),
      fluidRow(
         box(
            width = 12,
            includeHTML("first.html")
         )
      )
   )
)

ui2 <- dashboardPage(
   dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
   dashboardSidebar(),
   dashboardBody(
      box(width = 12,
          plotlyOutput("plot1")          
      )
   ),
   dashboardControlbar(
      fluidRow(
         box(
            width = 12,
            includeHTML("first.html")
         )
      )
   )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
   
   a = rnorm(100)
   output$plot1 = renderPlotly({
      plot_ly(x = ~a, type = "histogram")
   })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
## shinyApp(ui2, server) ## works likewise
```

### Screenshots

[image: Bootstrap 4 Dashboard wiht External HTML loaded properly]

[image: Bootstrap 4 Dashboard wiht External HTML loaded properly in the ControlBar]